# Can I use (not set) jndi values in web.xml under jboss 5 or later?

Tags: jboss, jndi, web.xml

I use org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr mbean to setup config under jboss 5.xx.
Can I use such bound values in web.xml? 
Sample

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>name</param-name>
       <param-value>{$value}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

where  {$value} is a value of a bound item.